# Python list of dictionaries projection, filter, or subset?

Tags: python, functional-programming, functools

I'm trying to create what I think is a 'projection' from a larger dictionary space onto a smaller dimension space.  So, if I have:

```
mine = [
{"name": "Al", "age": 10},
{"name": "Bert", "age": 15},
{"name": "Charles", "age": 17}
]
```

I'm trying to find a functional expression to return only:

```
[
{"name": "Al"},
{"name": "Bert"},
{"name": "Charles"}
]
```

I've tried...

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x['name'],mine)
[{'age': 10, 'name': 'Al'}, {'age': 15, 'name': 'Bert'}, {'age': 17, 'name': 'Charles'}]
>>> map(lambda x : x['name'],mine)
['Al', 'Bert', 'Charles']
```

But seem to still be missing the right function.  I know how to do it with a list comprehension, but would like to do learn how to do this functionally.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sounds like a job for list comprehensions, whether you like them or not.

```
>>> [{"name": d["name"]} for d in mine]
[{'name': 'Al'}, {'name': 'Bert'}, {'name': 'Charles'}]
```

The solution without a list comprehension would require an additional function definition:

```
def project(key, d):
    return {k: d[k]}

map(partial(project, "name"), mine)
```

Or a `lambda` (yuck):

```
map(lambda d: {"name": d["name"]}, mine)
```

Comment: Your lambda version returns `[set(['Al', 'name']), set(['Bert', 'name']), set(['Charles', 'name'])]`, ah got it, replace the comma with a colon.

Comment: @Mittenchops: oops, fixed that.

Comment: note that since python 3 map returns a map object. If you want a list you have to do `list(map(lambda d: {"name": d["name"]}, mine))`

Answer (score 1):

***CODE:***

```
print([{'name': d['name']} for d in mine])
```

***OUTPUT:***

```
[{'name': 'Al'}, {'name': 'Bert'}, {'name': 'Charles'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case we want to preserve more than one key:

```py
input_dicts = [
    {"name": "Al", "age": 40, "level": "junior"},
    {"name": "Bert", "age": 30, "level": "mid"},
    {"name": "Charles", "age": 20, "level": "senior"}
]

selected_keys = ("name", "level")

[
    {key: value for key, value in a_dict.items() if key in selected_keys}
    for a_dict in input_dicts
]
```

```py
[{'name': 'Al', 'level': 'junior'},
 {'name': 'Bert', 'level': 'mid'},
 {'name': 'Charles', 'level': 'senior'}]
```